# Is Possible To Create More Than 1 Master Layout - Layout Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new with Laravel, I just want to know may I create more than 1 master layout ?

Thankyou,

Comment: yes, you can create as many as you want. but be more specific on your question.

Comment: Thankyou @Wreigh ! yes specifically, I want to use more than 1 layout and I'm just afraid of an error when I try to create new layout.

Comment: You mean, more than 1 layout in a single blade page?

Comment: @Wreigh No, just a masterl-layout files in layouts folder. BTW, can I use multiple layouts in one page ? I don't think so...

Comment: of course yes. just clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create multiple layouts.

e.g

```
@extends('your layout 1')
@section('content)
@endsection
```

// second view

```
@extends('your layout 2')
@section('content)
@endsection
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou ! It helps, I just want to know and just afraid of getting an error